# Im getting no such table <table name> error when i retrieve the data from sqlite?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sqlite

I gave same name for table and database .But i am getting no such table found error.

```
sqlite3 *dbConnection = nil;
NSArray *documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [documentDirectory objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *documentPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"locations.sqlite"];
sqlite3_open([documentPath UTF8String], &dbConnection);

sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil;

@try {
    if(sqlite3_open([documentPath UTF8String], &dbConnection)!=SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_close(dbConnection);
    }
    else
    {

        //create editable database copy

    }
    NSString *selectQuery=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select * from address_locations"];
    const char * retrieveQuery = [selectQuery UTF8String];

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbConnection,retrieveQuery, -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            NSMutableDictionary * dictionaryAboutInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
            [dictionaryAboutInfo setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)] forKey:@"ZIP"];
            [dictionaryAboutInfo setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)] forKey:@"LATITUDE"];
            [dictionaryAboutInfo setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)] forKey:@"LONGITUDE"];
            ////NSLog(@"Retrived Dict values %@",dictionaryAboutInfo);
            [dealersInfoArray addObject:dictionaryAboutInfo];
            [dictionaryAboutInfo release];
        }
    }
    [selectQuery release];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {

}
@finally {
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(dbConnection);
}
```

Thanks for advance

Comment: You realize...if that database doesn't exist it is going to create a new one with no tables right?

Comment: @borrden :Yes, when i run the application im getting  zero size KB database file..

Comment: There is your problem then.  How can an empty database have any tables?

Comment: did u copied ur db to document directory ? or still in bundle ?

Comment: No tables are present in that database.when i print the error message im getting no such table address_locations ..

Comment: @Ramshad :i copied the database into bundle.

Comment: you are retrieving the tables from documentDirectory.. not from bundle!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 BOOL  success;
NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:documentPath];
if (success) 
{
    NSLog(@"file found at the document path"); 
}
//bundle path
NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"address_locations.sqlite"];
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:documentPath error:nil];
```

sqlite3_open([documentPath UTF8String], &dbConnection);

Comment: i added this code to the above code.Actually my problem is Sqlite file is not copied into the document directory.So,by using above code i solved the issue..

Answer (score 0):

I think your database file in bundle and you are retrieving the database from documentDirectory.. not from bundle!!!!

you can change the path as

```
 NSString *documentPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"locations.sqlite"];
```